# age verification pop up on not getting existing cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, handlebars.js

I have a age verification pop up when a user visits the site for the first time. I want to box to pop up when going to the site for the first time and not ask again unless closing out the browser and going back to the site. So far it works like it should, pop ups and creates the cookie. It isn't recognizing the cookie though when I visit other pages on the site and continues to pop up.

```js
function getBaseUrl(){return window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host}function getTemplate(e){var n=getBaseUrl()+handlebarTemplatesPath+e+".hbs";return jQuery.get(n).then(function(e){return Handlebars.compile(e)})}var handlebarTemplatesPath="/templates/components/common/";addAgeVerifyToBody=function(){getTemplate("age-verify").done(function(e){jQuery("body").append(e)})},jQuery(document).ready(function(){"true"!=Cookies.get("age-verified")&&addAgeVerifyToBody()}),overAge=function(){jQuery("#age-verify").addClass("hidden"),Cookies.set("age-verified","true")},underAge=function(){jQuery("#age-verify").addClass("under")},goBack=function(){window.history.back()};
```

```css
#age-verify {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 500ms;
}
#age-verify .window {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid Red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 500ms;
}
#age-verify .window span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#age-verify .window span.title {
  color: Red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#age-verify .window button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: Red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: .2s;
}
#age-verify .window button.back {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: Red !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#age-verify .window button.yes {
  float: left;
}
#age-verify .window button.no {
  float: right;
}
#age-verify .window button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #ff3333;
}
#age-verify .window .underBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 40px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: Red;
  transition: 500ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#age-verify .window .underBox * {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
#age-verify.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#age-verify.hidden .window {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
#age-verify.under .window .underBox {
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div id="age-verify">
  <div class="window">
    <span class="title">Are you over 21?</span>
    <span>To visit our website, you must be of legal drinking age.</span>
    <button class="yes" onclick="overAge()">Yes</button>
    <button class="no" onclick="underAge()">No</button>
    <div class="underBox">
      <span class="title">Sorry!</span>
      <span>You need to be at least 21 to visit our website.</span>
      <button class="back" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        window.onload = function() {
           checkCookie();
        };

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
        function checkCookie() {
            var user=getCookie("age-verified");
            if (user != "") {
                $("#age-verify").addClass("hidden");
            }
        }
        

        var yesEl = document.getElementById('yes');
        var noEl = document.getElementById('no');

        yesEl.addEventListener('click', function(){
            //document.cookie = 'age-verified; expires=1';
            $('#age-verify').addClass('hidden');
            function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*1));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }
        });

        noEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
            $('#age-text').addClass('hiddenText');
            $('#under-age').removeClass('hiddenText');
            $('#yes').addClass('hiddenText');
        });

    });
```

```css
#age-verify {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#age-verify .window {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid Red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#age-verify .window span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#age-verify .window span.title {
  color: Red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#age-verify .window button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: Red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transform: scale(1);
}
#age-verify .window button.back {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: Red !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#age-verify .window button.yes {
  float: left;
}
#age-verify .window button.no {
  float: right;
}
#age-verify .window button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #ff3333;
}
#age-verify .window .underBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 40px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: Red;
  transition: 500ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#age-verify .window .underBox * {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
#age-verify.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#age-verify.hidden .window {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
#age-verify.under .window .underBox {
  top: 0%;
}
.hiddenText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="age-verify">
  <div class="window">
    <div id="age-text">
      <span class="title">Are you over 21?</span>
      <span>You must be 21 to visit this website.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="under-age" class="hiddenText">
      <span class="title">Sorry!</span>
      <span>You need to be at least 21 to visit our website.</span>
    </div>
    <button id="yes" class="yes">Yes</button>
    <button id="no" class="no">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore or just didn't catch it the first time.. It's not recognizing the cookie or something because it pops up on every page